# AAD Token from SPA app works to call Nodejs API but not .Net WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a SPA application that uses MSAL to acquire a token from AAD.  Because MSAL works with v2 endpoint and because v2 endpoint does not currently support issuing tokens for custom API's, I'm passing the ID Token to my api and essentially treating my api as the same application.  (While this has a smell to it, it does actually work -- at least with Nodejs API).

**SPA app**

```
let idToken = Msal.Storage('localStorage').getItem(Msal.Constants.idTokenKey);

this.http.configure(config => {
   config.withBaseUrl("http://localhost:3001/")
   config.withDefaults({headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken}})
});

//Call API
this.http.fetch("account")
...
```

**Node.js API**

```
//Using express/passport
var BearerStrategy = require("passport-azure-ad").BearerStrategy;

var options = {
     identityMetadata: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/.well-known/openid-configuration/",
     clientID: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx",
     passReqtoCallback: false,
     validateIssuer: true,
     issuer: "http://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0"
};

app.get("/account",passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer',{session: false}),...
```

The above all works.  Once a user authenticates with the SPA, the token is passed and the call to the Node API works.

I'm now trying to replace the Nodejs API with a .Net WebAPI. I have the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
   new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
   {
      TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
         //Same ID as used for ClientID in Nodejs
         ValidAudience = "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
         ValidIssuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0",
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         AuthenticationType = "WebApi" //Tried both with and without this
      },
      Tenant = "{tenantid}"  //have tried both id and name
    }
)
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("account")]
public IHttpActionResult AccountProfile(){
   //Get Account information
   ....

   return Ok(profile);
}
```

However, when I point the SPA app to call the .Net api, I always get `Authorization has been denied for this request` .

Is there something I'm missing?

**Edit**

Incidentally, I've inspected the token that is being used.

The value I'm using for `clientID` (Nodejs) and `ValidAudience` (.Net) exactly match the `aud` claim in the token.  The `issuer` (Nodejs) and `ValidIssuer` (.Net) exactly match the `iss` claim in the token.  Lastly, the anywhere in my code where I've inserted {tenantid}, the actual value there matches exactly the `tid` claim in the token.

Comment: Do you need to use MSAL? ADAL seems more easily integrated at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue when switching from ADAL to MSAL and got it to work by using a similar approach like [this Github project](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-oauth-aspnet-codeflow). Specifically take a look at these files:

https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-oauth-aspnet-codeflow/blob/master/Api/Startup.cs
https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-oauth-aspnet-codeflow/blob/master/Api/OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider.cs

Update: Our Startup.cs:

```
        var provider = new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(
            string.Format(bc2Instace, tenant, policyId));
        var jwt = new JwtFormat(clientId, provider);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = jwt,
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to give this a shot.  Frustrating that it is more intuitive to integrate with AAD using Nodejs/Passport than with MS's own middleware in .Net.

Comment: Struggling to get this working.  I'm targetting .Net 4.6.1.  The `CustomValidatingJwtFormat` class derives from JwtFormat class which gets its `TokenValidationParameters` from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens`.  The compiler says that `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` does not contain a definition for `TokenValidationParameters`.  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` does contain a definition but then I get errors because compiler can't convert from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` to `System.IdentityModel.Tokens`  Any way to get around this?

Comment: See my updated answer. Unfortunately, I am not deep into how this works in detail

Comment: thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, I'm going in circles.  As I said, there is a conflict between the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` libraries.  The Microsoft library is a dependency of the `Microsoft.Owin` libraries that I'm using and the System library is necessary for the `JwtFormat` class to be happy.  But adding them both causes conflict.  May have to move to ADAL.

Comment: The class you mention is present in nuget package "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt". This is also where we get it from.

Comment: I have that nuget package but still get: `Reference to type 'TokenValidationParameters' claims it is defined in 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt', but it could not be found.`

Comment: You may need to use Version "4.0.4.403061554" of this package for the time being. This seems to be a "workaround" of sorts. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3017

Comment: Yeah, just found the same thing on SO.  That did the trick.  Thanks for all your help!